# Bolt-action rifle in the 15th-17th century

Tags: technology, alternate-history, firearms

Lets say a nation around this timeline was making research and advancements in firearms.  Other than a flintlock or breech-loader, is it possible for them to produce a repeating bolt-action rifle? Would this require an industrial revolution to happen?

Comment: since you have already asked this very same question for [submachine gun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/131349/30492) and [percussion rifle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/145878/30492), which insight are you missing that the other answer did not provide?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could a percussion rifle be produced in the 15th-17th century?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/145878/could-a-percussion-rifle-be-produced-in-the-15th-17th-century)  Basically the same question regarding a slightly different gun mechanism.

Comment: Bolt action rifles are manual. You can't have a repeating manual action otherwise it's no longer a manual action.

Comment: @Rob I think he means a magazine-fed bolt action rifle

Comment: @Rob You make a good point, please try to politely point out mistakes, what may seem obvious to you isn't necessarily obvious to someone else.  Made a minor edit to your comment.

Comment: @elemtilas How is that a possible duplicate? A flint-lock is not a bolt action rifle. Which is also a mistake that the OP seems to have made. Neither a breech-loader or a flintlock is a bolt action. Also suggesting an industrial revolution is somehow relevant seems so erroneous to me... how could that possibly be necessary?

Comment: @Rob -- It's a duplicate because "XYZ future tech widget in a past era, is it possible?" Doesn't really matter what the XYZ future tech widget is. Especially when it's the same OP asking the same question about a tightly grouped set of technologies. The answer is thus the same for all: *since you have already asked this very same question for submachine gun and percussion rifle, which insight are you missing that the other answer did not provide?*

Answer (score 1):

Eric,

I hope it is simple as well as sufficient to say that the 'modern' centerfire rifle ammunition - nevermind the mechanism that the firearm uses, is a product of mass-production era post-industrial revolution.  The cartridge needed for any contemporary firearm wasn't popular for this exact reason until around the American Civil War, c.1850.
  Handmade examples or powder/projectile cartridges existed prior to the 1800s, but any bolt/lever/semi-auto or other "repeating" rifle will use ammunition at a rate that was mostly cost-prohibitive until Henry Ford's day.
  In short, I feel certain that the mechanism of the rifle would be far overshadowed by the lack of ammunition, especially in post-renaissance Europe.